# Parse String From Web Service to a Json Object

Tags: android, json, parsing, httpresponse

I know there's lots of Questions about this, and lots of answers too, however I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem yet, and wondered if anyone had some ideas.

Please note, I'm new to Android and have unfortunately inherited this project from an Android developer that's no longer with us.

Here's what I'm dealing with.
I have an Android App, that calls a web service, and gets a response Stream.

I've tried to use 
`String ScanString = new Scanner(inStream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();`

which seems to work and results in a string as follows

`{"RegResponseResult":"{\u000d\u000a  \"REGISTERED\": true,\u000d\u000a  \"COMPANY_URL\": \"http:\/\/111.222.3.444\/ABC\/XYZ.svc\/\"\u000d\u000a}"}`

My Problem is .....
When I try to use `JSONObject JSONObj = new JSONObject(ScanString)` To Convert the string to a JSONObject, The Resutling Object Only has one nameValuePair.

ie: `key=RegResponseResult` and `value={  "REGISTERED": true, \r\n"COMPANY_URL": "http://111.222.3.444/ABC/XYZ.svc/"\r\n}`
}"

How can a jet a JsonObject, ignoring the 'RegResponseResult' , and using the Containing Tags instead, so that it ends up looking like this.

ie: JSONObj =

`Key=REGESTERD value=true 
 Key=COMPANY_URL value=http://111.222.3.444/ABC/XYZ.svc`

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: try `JSONObject inner = JSONObj.getJSONObject("RegResponseResult")`. The `inner` object will contain the two values you expect.

Comment: That Throws and Error:      Value {
  "REGISTERED": true,
  "COMPANY_URL": "http://111.222.333.444/ABC/XYZ.svc/"
} at RegResponseResult of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: the json string which you are getting is itself not in the format what are you trying to get. Json string should be like {"RegResponseResult":"{\u000d\u000a  \"REGISTERED\": true,\u000d\u000a}",
"COMPANY_URL": "{\"http:\/\/111.222.3.444\/ABC\/XYZ.svc\/\"\u000d\u000a}"}

Answer (score 0):

The `"RegResponseResult"` is string so you may have to re-parse it again to get the inner json object.

```
String innerJson = JSONObj.getString("RegResponseResult");
JSONObject inner = new JSONObject(innerJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the ideas.

I ended up changing my webservice, to output a stream instead of a string.
Turns out WCF Adds a bunch of \ to the string, which invalidates it as a Json String.

But returning it as a stream, doesn't result in anything being added.
Here's the Stream builder code for the webservice... if anyone else needs it.

```
    //When Reading the DB in the Iaaa.csv

    public Stream RegResponse(String DeviceData)
{
    // *****connect to db and call stored proc goes here****
    //  .................

    //  read parameters back from cmd object.
    DeviceRegisterResponse Response = new DeviceRegisterResponse();

    Response.REGISTERED = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.Parameters["REGISTERED"].Value);
    Response.COMPANY_URL = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["COMPANY_URL"].Value);
    return GenerateStreamFromString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Response, Formatting.None));
}


//When passsing it back from the service in the Iaaa.cs
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "REG/{id}")]
        Stream RegResponse(string id);
```